# contentflow add items via function

Tags: javascript, html, coverflow, contentflow

Hi I would like to add images to contentflow with a button. when you click the button function will be called and all the images will be loaded.
Here is my code.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' title='Standard' href='contentflow/cfstyles.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript' src='contentflow/contentflow.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='contentflow/jquery.min.js'></script>`  <div style='width:400px;height:200px;'  class='maincontent'>


<div id='contentFlow' class='ContentFlow'>       
    <div class='loadIndicator'><div class='indicator'></div></div>
    <div id='adddiv' class='flow'>
//images should come to here       
    </div>
    <div class='globalCaption'></div>
    <div class='scrollbar'>
        <div class='slider'><div class='position'></div></div>
    </div>

</div>

<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="start();" />`

<script tyle='text/javascript'>

function start(){
var cf = new ContentFlow('contentFlow', {reflectionColor: '#000000'});
$(document).ready(function() {
for (var i=0; i<15; i++ ){
$("#adddiv").prepend(" <div class='item'><img onclick='start(" + i + ");' class='content'   src='contentflow/pics/pic"+i+".png'/><div class='caption'>" + i + "</div></div>");

}
});
```

}

If I dont use button and function it diretly load all the images but if I want to load images with function it doesn't work.
What is the problem here?

Comment: The event which executes `$(document).ready()`, has been fired a long time before the execution comes into your `start()`...

Comment: I deleted it but doesn't make difference.

Comment: You need to rather move it above `start()` than delete.

Comment: This works: http://jsfiddle.net/QmmRa/

Comment: Check that the contentflow isn't causing an error.

Comment: not really. I removed it but still the same and still doesn't give any error that i can understand the reason. thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I made it work with following codes.

```
<div id='ajax_cf' class='ContentFlow'>
<div class='flow'> </div>
<div class='scrollbar'><div class='slider'><div class='position'></div></div></div>
```

```
<input type="button" value="get images!" onclick="getPictures();" />
```

```
var ajax_cf = new ContentFlow('ajax_cf');

function addPictures(){
    var ic = document.getElementById('itemcontainer');
    var is = ic.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i=0; i< is.length; i++) {
        ajax_cf.addItem(is[i], 'last');
    }
   }
function getPictures() {
for (var i=0; i<15; i++ ){
$("#itemcontainer").prepend("<img onclick='' class='content' src='contentflow/pics/pic0.png'/>");`
   }
 addPictures();
}
```